# Thread Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads in my program as follows:

```
class SendThread implements Runnable {
     public void run(){
           Thread.sleep(1000);

           while (true){    
                if (CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED){
                    // code here
                }
           } 
     } 
 } 

class ReceiveThread implements Runnable {
     public void run(){


           while (true){    
                // code here
                CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED = true;  

           }
     }
 }
```

I have defined `CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED` as a `static Boolean`.

In the second thread, the `Boolean` `CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED` is set to `true` at a certain point. If I don't use `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the 1st thread, after `CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED` is set to `true` in the 2nd thread I don't enter the relevant `if` statement in the 1st thread.

Is there another way around this? Because my 1st thread will often be dependent on variable changes in the second thread.

Comment: Thanks for editing this Martin. How do I put variables in that grey box like you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `volatile` keyword to  the `CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED` method and see.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing teh challenge because you are changing the static variable CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED in a non-synchronized way and you are not using the wait notify mechanism for thread communication. Using wait notify should help you. Create an object to be used for wait-notify and use the code as below

```
class SendThread implements Runnable {
     public void run(){
           Thread.sleep(1000);

           while (true){  
                synchronized(object)  {
                    object.wait();
                    if (CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED){
                       // code here

                    }
                }
           } 
     } 
 } 

class ReceiveThread implements Runnable {
     public void run(){


           while (true){   
                synchronized(object)  {
                   // code here
                   CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED = true;  
                   object.notify(); 
                  }
           }
     }
 }
```

I have not tested the code, i have just tried to put the concept so make changes as required.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example you can mark the CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED boolean as volatile and it will work as expected, other threads will see the change the next time they access the variable.

However I will warn you against using volatile for anything except the most simple cases (single variable update). It provides no atomicity so if you need to do more than a single assignment during an update it will not provided the necessary guarantees. This includes increments/decrements which are actually 3 operations, read/modify/write at the memory model level so requires proper synchronization.

In that case you should use a synchronized block around both the read AND write.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

private int shared1;
private int shared2;

public void write(int var1, int var2)
{
  sychronized (lock)
  {
    shared1 = var1;
    shared2 = var2;
  }
}

public int readSum()
{
  sychronized (lock)
  {
    int total = shared1 + shared2;
    return total;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that Mike. Your point is duly noted. I have started reading up on this.